# translating curl_setopt into asp.net header

Tags: php, asp.net, post, httpwebrequest

I have to address a Rest API from within an asp.net console application.
The first call is a Login to receive an Access token.
Unfortunately all examples are only in PHP which I read poorly.

The PHP example says:

```
use 'curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Authorization : Basic ".$encodedAuth));
```

and

```
Token Header: "Authorization: Basic {User,Colon,Password -> as Base64}"
```

Content-Type is `application/json.`

EDIT:
The user/pwd combination is set with the instruction:

```
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $api_username . ':' . $api_password);
```

What do I have to set in my httpwebrequest to transmit the authorization correctly?

I have tried

```
  Dim data As String = """grant_type"": ""client_credentials"""
  Dim postdata As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data)

  Dim req As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create(uploadURL), HttpWebRequest)
  req.Method = "POST"
  req.ContentType = "application/json;encoding=utf-8"
  req.ContentLength = postdata.Length
  req.Accept = "application/json"
  req.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(userID, userPW)
  req.Timeout = 600000
  req.Headers.Add("Authorization", userID & ":" & userPW)
```

but continue to receive a Code 400.
Any help appreciated

Comment: I think the example are teling you that you must convert a json like: {"User":"myUser","Colon":"myColon","Password":"mypassworn"} into a base64. then: Authorization : Basic ".$encodedAuth where $encodedAuth is the base64

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is the solution:

```
     Dim data As String = "{""grant_type"": ""client_credentials""}"
     Dim postdata As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data)

     Dim uploadURL As String = "https://api.dreamrobot.de/rest/v1.0/token.php"
     Dim userID As String = "xxxxxxx"
     Dim userPW As String = "xxxxxxx"

     Dim req As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create(loginURL), HttpWebRequest)
     req.Method = "POST"
     req.ContentType = "application/json;encoding=utf-8"
     req.ContentLength = postdata.Length
     req.Accept = "application/json"
     req.Timeout = 600000
     req.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " & Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(userID & ":" & userPW), Base64FormattingOptions.None))

     Dim _stream As Stream = req.GetRequestStream()
     _stream.Write(postdata, 0, postdata.Length)
     _stream.Close()

     Dim _response As HttpWebResponse = req.GetResponse()
     Dim _reader As New StreamReader(_response.GetResponseStream)
     data = _reader.ReadToEnd
     _reader.Close()
     _response.Close()
```

The PHP setopt CURLOPT_USERPWD function creates a http Header entry "Authorization:" which needs the value "Basic " & base64(user:pwd).
The important Point is to do the conversion into base64string WITHOUT linefeed, hence the Base64FormattingOptions.None.

The use case here is to address the DreamRobot Rest API, here the first call to receive an Access token.